# Capitalize after slash at beginning (e.g. Risk/Issue management)

Tags: capitalization, sentence-starts, slash

Should a word after a slash at the beginning of a sentence be capitalized?

E.g.

> 1. Risk/Issue management
> 2. Risk/issue management

I would guess the first one is correct because "Issue" would be an alternative beginning due to the slash.

Comment: You are right, thought not quite "because *Issue* would be an alternative beginning" but because both "Risk" and "Issue" have context-sensitive meanings. Here these words mean exactly as defined for the purpose of the context and not the general meaning.

Comment: I cannot quite follow you. What is difference between context-sensitive and general meaning and why does it impact the capitalization?

Comment: In lists of terms like that only the first cap is used, generally. Unless you are referring to titles of some kind, which case management should also be in caps.

Answer (score 14):

For a sentence, only capitalise the first word:

> Risk/issue management is important because it will help you highlight ...

For a title, capitalise all words as usual:

> **Risk/Issue Management**

Alternatively reword to remove the slash:

> **Risk and Issue Management**
>
> Risk and issue management is important because it will help you highlight ...

Comment: I think here *slash* is used for the *or* risk or issue management?

Comment: Well, if you're managing them, you want to manage both.

Comment: Any references to back this up?

Comment: Actually it should be an example for "Risk OR issue management"

Answer (score 2):

- In this British site it is lower case: [queens-english-society.com](http://queens-english-society.com/punctuation_guide.html#slash)

> **The Slash [ / ]**
>
> The slash is also known as the solidus, the slant, the oblique or oblique stroke or simply the stroke.
>
> ...
>
> to show alternatives:
>
> (i) Your coach/train/boat/plane ticket;
>
> (ii) **He/she** should go...
>
> Both the forward slash (/) and the backslash (\) are used in computing.

- In this US-based site there is a space and upper case is kept:
  [UCLA.edu](http://map.ais.ucla.edu/portal/site/UCLA/menuitem.b1e4ec4b9bd97a2dffc9ca10f848344a/?vgnextoid=5bc73189cc2f1010VgnVCM1000008f8443a4RCRD&vgnextfmt=print)

> **slash (/)**
>
> Add one space after a slash.
>
> **Payroll/ Personnel**
>
> receipt/ invoice

Comment: The second link seems to be broken

Comment: So in conclusion both variations seems to be possible?

Comment: The conclusion so far is that British suggest not and UCLA's rules suggest to keep the initial cap. See new link. Perhaps it is session based :(

Comment: That extra space in the UCLA suggestion looks messy. Maybe it's just a way of fooling some specific search or line-break function into treating the second option as a whole word?

Comment: I would have to ask UCLA :)

Comment: @mplungjan Re:"The conclusion so far" That doesn't surprise me. We Brits have a tendency to capitalise less than AmE does in other areas also, e.g. in titles & headings.

Comment: Wonder how that answers the question at hand.

Comment: queens-english society does not, the UCLA writing guide does. Why is that not relevant to give an indication of what to do if British or US? I could not find anywhere a hard rule in OED or similar, so this is as close as it gets for me. If useful for the asker, great. Obviously not good enough for you, so find a better source.

Comment: The general recommendation is to use a spaced slash only when the elements it is separating themselves contain spaces. And even them, the spacing should be symmetric. Also, one should only ever use a real slash, not a backslash, for such separations. I don’t much like slashes in regular prose myself.